# loop is not working - clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, clone

i have this code, but is not working.

Probably i can't make this with two divs (?)

```
 var newElem = $('#input' + num, '#valores'+num).clone(true).prop('id', 'input' + newNum, 'id', 'valores' + newNum);
```

script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#input' + num, '#valores'+num).clone(true).prop('id', 'input' + newNum, 'id', 'valores' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':text').prop('name', "myformdata[valor][]").prop('valor', 'valor').val('');
            $('#input' + num, '#valores' + num).after(newElem);
        }
        });
    </script>


    <div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
        <ol id="valores1">
            <li>lowest</li>
            <li>highest</li>
        </ol>
    <input readonly id="sliderProgInput" size="20" type="hidden" name="myformdata[valor][]"/>
    </div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NjpVA/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply it to two divs like that. Apply it to each one separately.